# How to install NVIDIA GeForce GTX 675M in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, laptop, samsung

Can someone tell me the steps to install NVIDIA GeForce GTX 675M?

My laptop is a SAMSUNG Series 7 NP700G7C-S01US. I have Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

See this link: http://tech.sixcolumns.com/2012/11/nvidia-310-19-drivers-released-how-to-install-it-in-ubuntu-12-1012-04/

It has instructions for how to install the drivers for your graphics card.